# Custom syntax highlighting on current buffer in vim

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

From time to time I would like to apply some custom extra syntax highlighting on the current buffer.

How can this be done using the build in vim syntax/highlight system (I do not want to use the Highlight plugin)

As example, I would like to highlight all assert statements in current buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the highlighting is for certain filetypes (e.g. Java) only, and you want it all the time, I'd extend the original syntax with `:syn match ...` definitions placed in `~/.vim/after/syntax/java.vim`.

For spontaneous highlighting, use `:match` (or `:2match`), as *dwalter* has shown.

If you're gonna write a more elaborate mapping, maybe with toggling on/off logic, use `matchadd()` / `matchdelete()`.

Finally, if you need highlighting for arbitrary words / strings, like marking up a document with a text marker, I'd suggest the comfort of a plugin like [Mark](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666) (which I have taken over maintaining).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `match` and `highlight` if you want.

example:

```
    :hi MyAsserts term=bold ctermbg=Cyan
    :match MyAsserts /assert(.*)/
```

to highlight your `assert()` statements with Cyan background.
`:match` without any arguments will reset it.

for more information on either `highlight` or `match` look at the documentation via
`:help hi` or `:help match`

To reuse your highlighting you can save those commands in a file and use `:source file.vim` to load it anytime you want. Another way would be to define a command inside your `.vimrc`.

```
     hi MyAsserts ctermbg=Cyan
     command -bar -nargs=0 HiAsserts match MyAsserts /assert(.*)/
     "highlight any given regex
     command -bar -nargs=1 HiIt match MyAsserts /<args>/
```

and call it with `:HiAsserts` to highlight your `assert()` statements or `:HiIt foo` to highlight every `foo` in your buffer.